# how to create pretty urls

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have a URL from my website like this - 
`http://www.mydomain.com/profiles/centers/index.php?code=2507&name=Tharanga+Higher+Educational+Institute#page=art-section`

I need to display above url as friendly url on my browser's address bar when it going to above page.

My expecting url something like this -

```
http://mydomain.com/centers/Tharanga-Higher-Educational-Institute#page=art-section
```

This code so far in my .htaccess file

```
# Enable Rewriting 
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /profiles/centers/index.php\?code=([0-9]+)&name=([^&]+)&?([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^profiles/centers/index\.php /%1/?%2 [R=301,L,NE]
```

But this code is not working for me. hope someone will help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: Because it is a clean URL you require and not a redirect, in your current circumstance I would use `php` to remove characters between `http://www.mydomain.com/profiles/centers/` and `Tharanga+Higher+Educational+Institute#page=art-section`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+profiles/centers/index\.php\?code=([^&]+)&name=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /profiles/centers/index.php?code=$1&name=$2 [L,NC,QSA,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpe?g|gif|png)$ /profiles/centers/%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R=302]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: I checked it with your code. Now I can get this error massege - `Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404`

Comment: Can I know what does it mean?

Comment: What is the URL that you see in the browser after redirect?

Comment: Also if you enter this URL directly into your browser: `http://mydomain.com/centers/Tharanga-Higher-Educational-Institute#page=art-section` is it working for you?

Comment: @anbhava I checked it according to your above comment. But it is not working for me. I am using href link `http://www.mydomain.com/profiles/centers/index.php?code=2507&name=Tharanga+Higher+Educational+Institute` from my index.php page to goto the profile page. In profile page I need to have such a pretty url on browser's address bar.

Comment: Will you be willing to keep the pretty URL as: `http://mydomain.com/centers/2507/Tharanga-Higher-Educational-Institute#page=art-section` as you cannot omit the code from pretty URL since you backend will need it to load the page? If yes then I can edit my anser to cater to that requirement.