# Creating a Pretty URL

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

It almost is similar to [how to create pretty urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747543/how-to-create-pretty-urls) but, it does not seem to work for me.

Here is my url:

```
http://localhost/pr/ajax/ajax_load.php?task=get_blob&blid=199
```

How do I convert it to:

```
http://localhost/pr/ajax/get_blob/199
```

Here is my **.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pr/ajax/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+pr/ajax/ajax_load\.php\?task=([&\s]+)&blid=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /pr/ajax/ajax_load.php?task=$1&blid=$2 [L,NC,QSA,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpeg|gif|png|pdf)$ /pr/ajax/%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R=302]
```

Where should the **.htaccess** be placed? I mean, does it matter where you put it at? My **root** is at `pr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/pr/ajax/(.*)/(.*)$ /pr/ajax/ajax_load.php?task=$1&blid=$2 [NC,L]
```

And yes, it does matter where you put the htaccess file. You put the file in the directory of the file whose path you want to modify/manipulate.

Answer (score 4):

The location of the .htaccess file is important, specially for the URI-path tested in the rewrite rule, that contains only the path segment after the directory where the file is located. To overcome that limitation, only the REQUEST_URI variable is used in the following code.

Here is a **tested** solution that works with .htaccess file at either `/pr` or `/pr/ajax/` directories:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pr/ajax/ajax_load\.php\?task=([^&]+)&blid=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule .*             /pr/ajax/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ajax_load\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pr/ajax/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? [NC]
RewriteRule .*  /pr/ajax/ajax_load.php?task=%1&blid=%2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: This is amazing. I thought I needed to reprogram HTTP GET. But, it seems to work just fine automatically to all GET methods. Thanks!